# Best way to markup the Lightning Design System Input Field

Tags: visualforce, design, lightning-design-system

I was going through the documentation for using the Lightning Design System in Visualforce pages and I noticed what seems to be an inconsistency with how they markup the Input fields.

In the [official documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#input) when they list the Input Field by itself they use the following example.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="sample1">Text Input</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <input id="sample1" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Which uses an outer div to hold a Label and an inner div (which is a sibling of the Label) that holds the Input Field.

However later on when using a [Compound Form](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#compound-form) the example provided has the Label wrap the Input Field as well as a span

```
  <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2">
    <span class="slds-form-element__helper">Latitude</span>
    <input class="slds-input" type="text" />
  </label>
```

I've tried both forms outside of a Compound Form and they appear the same.  Putting both forms inside the Compound Form makes the first example display oddly.

[image]

Is it better to use the second form in all instances or should the markup be different depending on how it's used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [component overview](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#overview) in the docs supports using the `slds-form-element__label` element.

The [Github repo for the winter-16 release](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/winter-16/ui/components/forms/flavors/form-element/index.scss) suggests that the `__helper` element is just styling the input to font-size small, whereas the `__label` element sets spacing as well and also supports the use of a required modifier.

This makes me think that the second form IS indeed just for compound forums. There's a lot to be desired in docs for this situation.